# Should I ask a question about bad breath here?

Tags: discussion

First, I would like to say that it took some time for me to understand from my co-worker's explanation, but I believe that the concept of a "meta" Q&A site is a genius idea! Kudos to whoever came up with that idea!

That aside, I have a question about mouthwash and controlling morning breath that I would like to be able to ask on a Q&A site like "Seasoned Advice." I looked through all of the sites that are available on "Area 51," but couldn't find anything with an actual community.

I know this site is about cooking, and bad breath is only very loosely related (if at all!), so I don't want to violate the terms of use if this is too much of a stretch.

If not, what should I do? Is there a "meta-meta" site where I can ask what site would be the best place to pose my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to meta, and thanks for asking!

> a question about mouthwash and controlling morning breath

... is currently *not* on topic at [any of our existing Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). I'm struggling to think what expert community this would be appropriate for, other than perhaps a general medical practitioner or health Q&A?

Perhaps something like

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health

But this site proposal is still in the definition phase.

(also, we have discussed the need for a "magic 8 ball" feature on http://stackexchange.com to direct people to the correct site for their question.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suppose I could always ask my dentist for now :)